# Key Value Coding - setValue:forKey: where value is NULL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, key-value-coding

I am reading documentation that says `setValue:forKey:` will treat a `NULL` value as if it is being removed. Yet, I have an example such as the following that is consistently crashing:

`[myObj setValue:[aDictionary valueForKey:@"keyDoesNotExist"] forKey:@"anotherKey"];`

This line of code crashes if `aDictionary` does not contain the key `keyDoesNotExist`. Is there any way around that? What's the appropriate thing to do here?

myObj is an instance of `NSManagedObject`. "anotherKey" is a one to many relationship where myObj can contain many of "anotherKey".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `setValue:forKey:` with a nil value, the method `-setNilValueForKey:` is called. By default (in NSObject's implementation), this raises an invalid argument exception. You can do something else with a nil value by overriding `-setNilValueForKey:` and doing whatever you'd like.

Alternatively, if you call myObj's anotherKey setter directly, you shouldn't get an exception (dependent on the implementation of `setAnotherKey:` of course):

```
myObj.anotherKey = [aDictionary valueForKey:@"keyDoesNotExist"];
```

The documentation you're reading is probably for NSMutableDictionary. NSMutableDictionary's implementation of `setValue:forKey:` calls `removeObjectForKey:` if the value is nil. That's not true for NSObject subclasses, which I'm presuming is what myObj is.

This behavior is discussed in the [NSKeyValueCoding Protocol Reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setNilValueForKey:).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. even when I've gone ahead and defined setNilValueForKey:, I'm getting an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. aDictionary definitely exists and there's other keys in it, but not the keyDoesNotExist key.

Comment: My answer didn't take into account the fact that myObjc is an NSManagedObject as you hadn't added that to your question yet. That said, EXC_BAD_ACCESS indicates a memory management error, likely because you're sending a message to (calling a method on) an object that has been deallocated. In other words, it's probably a memory management problem, rather than a problem with calling `setValue:ForKey:` with a nil value. Without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to diagnose. Try running your program using Instruments' Zombies instrument.

Comment: You should add NSZombieEnabled with a value of YES as an Environment Variable of your executable. Then re-run your code. If it is a zombie, you will get an error message in the console like "-[MyClass methodName] message sent to deallocated instance."

Comment: I'd like to mention that calling "[self setNilValueForKey:key];" on an NSManagedObject does not actually raise an NSInvalidArgumentException if you do not override the method. I can't quite figure out why this is the case. My assumption is that NSManagedObject overrides this method to set the appropriate nil value for the property type, but I can find no clear documentation or indication of this.

Comment: I believe after reading the conversation to end, that the question and accepted answer are now confused.  since the question was modified,  the answer that "raises an invalid argument exception" is not correct on an NSManagedObject,  since "nil" is a valid entry on NSManagedObject,  and NSManagedObject is not "typed" for "value".  which is why it does not raise an NSInvalidArgumentException.   correct me if I am wrong?